# 4-Bromo, 2,4-di-methylhexane and 3-Bromo, 3,5-di-methylhexane are the same thing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Came across the following question. The answer only says that option 3 is incorrect which is I agree to but dont you think option 4 is also incorrect. As per IUPAC rules isnt it the Halide that should get lowest possible number (in this case number 3 instead of 4) or is it both are same ? I am confused please help.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Both names, ‘4-bromo-2,4-dimethylhexane’ and ‘3-bromo-3,5-dimethylhexane’ are unambiguous and describe the same compound. However, only ‘4-bromo-2,4-dimethylhexane’ is in accordance with IUPAC recommendations.

First of all, the *seniority order of functional classes*, which is used to choose the functional class (here: …hexane), does not apply to *numbering of locants within the same compound class.*

Concerning numbering of locants within the same compound class, the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (…)

Furthermore,

> **P-14.3.5** Lowest set of locants
>
> The lowest set of locants is defined as the set that, when compared term by term with
> other locant sets, each cited in order of increasing value, has the lowest term at the first
> point of difference; (…)

Therefore, the example is correctly named as **4-bromo-2,4-dimethylhexane** rather than 3-bromo-3,5-dimethylhexane since the locant set ‘2,4,4’ is lower than ‘3,3,5’.

[image: 4-bromo-2,4-dimethylhexane]

Answer (score 0):

According to the IUPAC organic chemistry nomenclature, alkyl groups take precedence over halide groups so (4) is correct.

Similarly, C=C double bonds also take precedence over halides so (3) is incorrect and should be 2-bromoprop-1-ene.

(2) is also incorrect as there are only five carbons in the chain not six so the correct name is 4-oxo**pentan**oic acid.

A table of functional group priorities can be found [here](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/).

Comment: But if we follow that then 2-Bromo- 3-methyl butane never exists. But it pretty much does exist.

Comment: 2-bromo-3-methyl butane exists but it is not the correct IUPAC name for that molecule. the correct name is 3-bromo-2-methyl butane

Comment: The additional comment is not correct. According to rule P-14.4 (g) in the current IUPAC Blue Book (2013), the systematic name is **2-bromo-3-methylbutane** (not 3-bromo-2-methylbutane).

Comment: Nice catch on the oxopentanoic acid!

Answer (score -2):

Acc. to IUPAC we have to give lowest locant no. to side chain which in this case is 2-Bromo-2,4-dimethyl.
Another reason of this ans. being correct is that we take halides as a normal side chain and it is not given priority over methyl, we just only see lowest locant in this case.